# Json.NET or cjson

Tags: c#, json

anyone know which is better (setup, usage, flexibility, performance) obviously in your personal opinion/experience and applied work with these?

[JSon.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) or [cjson](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csjson/) ??

I have not used either and was about to create my own parser which I realize is a whole different ballgame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm personally a fan of [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) for the reason that it handles date serialization correctly using [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) instances.  From my experience, neither the [`DataContractJsonSerializer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) nor the [`JavaScriptSerializer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) handle this situation correctly; they both assume it is not a scalar type and make a mess of those instances by trying to export all the properties of the object (when in reality it should be serialized as a call to `new Date...`).

I also like that you an work with JSON data dynamically using Json.NET.  That's a *massive* boon if you aren't working with statically typed data.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I know datetime is the biggest hurdle in parsing engines so that's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Think of using serializer provided by Microsoft in .Net [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8.1) : [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303183506/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx)

Comment: we need to deserialize into a .NET object...custom object.  Also, APIs like Facebook have a very complex json structure.  We need something that can handle parsing these strings into a custom object..

Comment: And deserializer provided by MS can't handle it ? Look at blog post

Comment: I'm not using this.  It was depreciated in .NET 3.5 which is why I have refrained from using it.

Comment: So if json.net fulfils your needs you should use it instead of cjson, because cjson is still in alpha. I don't think you should use it in production :)

Comment: ah...did not know cjson was that new.  Thanks Jerek.  Have you used json.net?

Comment: oh did not see this yet but for cjson looks like it is dead: As of 2009-10-09 0:00:00 GMT, this project is no longer under active development.

Comment: Simple serializing/deserializing is here: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ReadingWritingJSON.html
documentation for json.net is really good:
http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

Comment: thanks looks like json.net is really the only library out there that's decent if any.  Plust docs are REAL important so that's a huge +